# NPE and InvocationTargetException error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, invocationtargetexception

This is the log:

```
02-16 21:19:48.532: D/OpenGLRenderer(22826): Render dirty regions requested: true
02-16 21:19:48.538: D/Atlas(22826): Validating map...
02-16 21:19:48.648: I/Adreno-EGL(22826): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/28/14, c33033c, Ia6306ec328
02-16 21:19:48.650: I/OpenGLRenderer(22826): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-16 21:19:48.674: D/OpenGLRenderer(22826): Enabling debug mode 0
02-16 21:19:56.921: D/AndroidRuntime(22826): Shutting down VM
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826): Process: com.example.mythirdapp, PID: 22826
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4002)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    ... 10 more
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long com.example.edit.DatabaseClass.insertRecord(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    at com.example.edit.CreateActivity.save_send(CreateActivity.java:79)
02-16 21:19:56.925: E/AndroidRuntime(22826):    ... 13 more
02-16 21:19:58.460: I/Process(22826): Sending signal. PID: 22826 SIG: 9
02-16 21:19:58.878: D/OpenGLRenderer(23137): Render dirty regions requested: true
02-16 21:19:58.885: D/Atlas(23137): Validating map...
02-16 21:19:58.924: I/Adreno-EGL(23137): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/28/14, c33033c, Ia6306ec328
02-16 21:19:58.926: I/OpenGLRenderer(23137): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-16 21:19:58.959: D/OpenGLRenderer(23137): Enabling debug mode 0
```

The Database:

```
public class DatabaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private DatabaseClass dbHelper;

    Context contextt;
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_ITEMS="items";
    public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION="description";
    public static final String KEY_DATE="date";
    public static final String KEY_SEND_STATUS="send_status";

    public static final String DB_NAME="g_shop";
    public static final String DB_TABLE="shop_record";

    public static final int DB_VERSION=1;

    public static final String DB_CREATE="create table if not exists shop_record ("+
                                        "ID int not null auto_increment,"+
                                        "items varchar(255),"+
                                        "description varchar(255),"+
                                        "date datetime,"+
                                        "send_status char(10),"+
                                        "primary key (ID));";

    public DatabaseClass(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        version = DB_VERSION;
        factory=null;
        name = DB_NAME;
        context=contextt;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DB_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public long insertRecord (String items, String description, String date, String send_status) {
        initialValues.put(KEY_ITEMS, items);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        initialValues.put(KEY_SEND_STATUS, send_status);
        return db.insert(DB_TABLE, KEY_DESCRIPTION, initialValues);

    }

}
```

The activity:

```
public class CreateActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DatabaseClass dbHelper;
    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_create);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.create, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void save(View v){
        EditText theitems = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText thedescription = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String items = theitems.getText().toString();
        String description=thedescription.getText().toString();
        String send_status="no";
        String date = s.format(new Date());
    }

    public void save_send(View v){
        EditText theitems = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText thedescription = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        String items = theitems.getText().toString();
        String description=thedescription.getText().toString();
        String send_status="yes";
        String date = s.format(new Date());
        long success = dbHelper.insertRecord(items, description, date, send_status);
        if (success == -1)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

I'm fairly new to OOP. I cant figure out why it is an NPE, I have initialised the variables in the struct, I am passing the right formats into the insertRecord method.

Comment: Where do you initialize `CreateActivity.dbHelper`? Looks to me like it's always null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: When I do initialise it: dbHelper = new DatabaseClass(dbHelper.contextt, dbHelper.DB_TABLE,null, dbHelper.DB_VERSION); I still get an Invocation error and an NPE on context. Can I initilaise context to null?

Comment: I don't see where that happens.  It must be happening after insertRecord is called.  Also, how can you refer to members of an uninitialized object during the initialization of that object? `x = new X(x.y)` can't be right. Should that be `dbHelper = new DatabaseClass(DatabaseClass.context, DatabaseClass.DB_TABLE, null, DatabaseClass.DB_VERSION)`?

Answer (score 0):

`dbHelper` is null. It is not initialized in the constructor and never populated anywhere is in the class.

Comment: When I do initialise it:
`dbHelper = new DatabaseClass(dbHelper.contextt, dbHelper.DB_TABLE,null, dbHelper.DB_VERSION);` I still get an Invocation error

Comment: And an NPE on Context

Comment: You cannot reference `dbHelper.context` before you have created `dbHelper`.